# Is there a function in ATSLIB to check if one string is a substring of another?

Tags: ats

For instance, "tween" is a substring of "between" but "teen" is not. Basically, I am looking for a function like `strstr` in libc.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a `strstr` function](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/LIBRARY/prelude/SATS/DOCUGEN/HTML/string.html#strstr) in the ATS prelude as well. See [a working example](https://glot.io/snippets/ek4nuahbuq) with all common combinations of the "haystack" and "needle" strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you target JavaScript, please use the function `string_indexOf`.
It takes two strings `haystack` and `key`; if it returns -1, then `key` does not occur in `haystack`; otherwise, it returns a non-negative integer referring to the position of the leftmost occurrence of `key` in `haystack`.